# scala combinations function hitting GC overhead

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following process which takes a list of Strings and generates combinations of it:

```
val a = List(("a","a"),("a","b"),("a","c"),("b","a"),("b","b"),("b","c"),("c","a"),("c","b"),("c","c"));
```

and I am trying to generate a list of combinations of 3 (because 3 is the number of distinct letters in the set) where each member left is only mapped to 1 distinct member on the right and vise-versa.

So for example, the output I expect is something like:

```
List(("a","a"),("b","b"),("c","c"))
```

but it cannot be something like:

```
List (("a","a"),("b","a"),("a","c"))
```

so I've written the following:

```
val res = a
  .combinations(3)
  .toList
  .filter(x =>
    x.map(y => y._1).distinct.size == 3
    &&  x.map(y => y._2).distinct.size == 3 
  )
```

which generates the correct set of answers:

```
List((a,a), (b,b), (c,c))
List((a,a), (b,c), (c,b))
List((a,b), (b,a), (c,c))
List((a,b), (b,c), (c,a))
List((a,c), (b,a), (c,b))
List((a,c), (b,b), (c,a))
```

but when I increase the size of a along with the number of combinations, I am hitting GC overhead. I was wondering if there is a way to do what I want without using the combination function or in a way that is more efficient? I am using Spark, so I could use any Spark function on this as well - though I don't think there is any.

Comment: are you aware that you're doing none of this with Spark? you're passing the _result_ of your (local) calculation to `sc.parallelize`, and then you do _nothing_ with the parallel dataset (RDD) that is created... So Spark isn't actually doing any work in this code

Comment: @TzachZohar yes I know - in fact I collect them to the master to use the combination function in scala as spark does not do it. I could create a Combinations of 2 using `cartesian` but that is beside the question. If you have a way to do it in Spark on a RDD I would gladly accept that answer :)

Comment: The `toList` will kill you if your input gets large.  Try streaming combinations rather than building a giant list up front.

Comment: if you're collecting to use `combinations` you assume the dataset won't be too large for your single-process driver to handle; If that's the case - why use Spark to begin with?

Comment: @BrianPendleton hmmm, that's true, will give it a try.

Comment: @TzachZohar using Spark because the previous process which generates the RDD/List which I am doing combinations on is on Spark and is parallelized. Again, I am only collecting because the `combinations` function does not work on RDDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, indeed Spark doesn't have a `combinations` function, but you can mimic it using consecutive calls to `cartesian`. It might not be too efficient in terms of performance, but it should prevent the memory issues you've come across and resolve the need to `collect` (which has its own performance cost):

```
val values: RDD[(String, String)] = sc.parallelize(a)
val combinationSize = 3 // can be increased

// mimic Scala's "combination" by repeating RDD.cartesian N times:
val combinations: RDD[Set[(String, String)]] = (1 until combinationSize)
  .foldLeft(values.map(Set(_))) {
    case (rdd, index) => rdd.cartesian(values).map { case (set, t2) => set + t2 }.distinct
  }

// removing "illegal" combinations - since we're using sets we don't need to call "distinct": 
val res = combinations
  .filter(_.map(_._1).size == combinationSize)
  .filter(_.map(_._2).size == combinationSize)
```